# Polymer - Firebase - getting child_added Name

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polymer, firebase-polymer

In polymer, I am READing a Firebase Table.
I can populate the Object and retrieve the data.
But I do not know how to get the Document name from the JSON...

This is example of my Data...

```html
{
    "PF004" : {
      "BINTS01" : 1477921088227,
      "BINTS02" : "2016-10-31 09:38",
      "BinScanWeekNumber" : 45,
      "DriversInitials" : "lt",
      "MissionID" : "lt1477921031516",
      "Q10_FILL_LEVEL" : "01 - 010% -2",
      "Q20_BIN_STATUS" : "300 - ALL GOOD",
      "ValLat" : 27.0026283,
      "ValLong" : -82.1632471,
      "YearNumber" : 2016,
      "recorded" : false
    },
    "PF009" : {
      "BINTS01" : 1477938700818,
      "BINTS02" : "2016-10-31 14:31",
      "BinScanWeekNumber" : 45,
      "DriversInitials" : "lt",
      "MissionID" : "lt1477935967751",
      "Q10_FILL_LEVEL" : "09 - 090% -5",
      "Q20_BIN_STATUS" : "300 - ALL GOOD",
      "ValLat" : 27.4861796,
      "ValLong" : -82.4469888,
      "YearNumber" : 2016,
      "recorded" : false
    },
```

Observe the "PF004" first record.

In Chrome debuger, I get this....
"Firebase child_added: PF004 "

So I know that chrome see's this.  I am looking for a way to print the Document ID.

This is what I have tried so far...

```html
                  <div class="card-content">BIN = [[bin.ID]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BIN = [[bin.id]] </div>
                  <div class="card-content">BIN = [[bin.child_added]] </div>
```

I am usually doing Android and ObjC stuff...  I really should know JS better than this...  thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `<firebase-query>` there should be a `bin.$key` property that contains e.g. `PF004`.